# Angular-cli----> CRUD operation update employee data not displaying name field but displaying other fields

Tags: css, angular, angular2-template, angular2-components

wen i click on edit table i am not able to view my name in the list of data available..

[here are the details of the table that i have added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSui9.png)

[after clicking the edit button i am not able to view my name field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktW4g.png)

here is the code of app.component.html

```
<h5>{{title}}</h5>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="createEmp()">Create Employee</button>
  </div>
<div style="margin-top: 60px;">

<div class = "container">
  <div *ngIf="add">
<h2>Add Employee:</h2>
<form class="form-horizontal" #empForm="ngForm">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="name">Name:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text"  class="form-control"  minlength="4" name="name" [(ngModel)]="model.name" placeholder="Enter Your Name" #name="ngModel" required/>
        <div *ngIf="name.invalid && (name.dirty || name.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
          <div *ngIf="name.errors.required">
            Name is required.
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="name.errors.minlength">
            Name must be at least 4 characters long.
          </div>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="position">Position:</label>

      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="position" [(ngModel)]="model.position" placeholder="Enter your position" required />
</div>
</div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="salary">Salary:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="salary" [(ngModel)]="model.salary" placeholder="Enter Salary" required />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" (click)="addEmployee()" [disabled]="empForm.invalid">Add Employee</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<div *ngIf="edit">

  <h2>Update Employee:</h2>
  <form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="name">Name:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name"
               name="name" [(ngModel)]="model2.name"  placeholder="Enter Your Name"/>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="position">Position:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="position" name="position" [(ngModel)]="model2.position" placeholder="Enter your position" required/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="salary">Salary:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="salary" name="salary" [(ngModel)]="model2.salary" placeholder="Enter Salary" required/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" (click)="updateEmployee()">update Employee</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<div *ngIf="Show">
<h2>Employee Details</h2>
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th width=400>Name</th>
        <th width=400>Position</th>
        <th width=200>Salary</th>
    <th width=400>Actions</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let employee of employees; let i=index">
        <td>{{employee.name}}</td>
        <td>{{employee.position}}</td>
        <td>{{employee.salary}}</td>
    <td>
    <a class="btn btn-success" (click)="editEmployee(i)">Edit</a>
        <a class="btn btn-danger" (click)="deleteEmployee(i)">Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

here is the data of app.component.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup , Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';



@Component({

  selector: 'app-root',

  templateUrl: './app.component.html',

  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']

})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  model:any={};
  model2:any={};
  edit= false;
  add=false;
  create=true;
  Show=false;
  myValue;
  ngOnInit(){
    this.model = new FormGroup({
      'name': new FormControl(this.model.name, [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(4),
      ]),
      'position': new FormControl(this.model.position),
      'salary': new FormControl(this.model.salary, Validators.required)
    });
  }
  title = 'Employee Details';
  employees = [{name :"Sunil",  position : "Developer", salary : 20000},
    {name :"Vamshi", position : "Java Developer",  salary : 30000},
    {name : "Chethan", position : ".Net Developer", salary : 10000}];
  createEmp(){
   this.add=true;
   this.create=false;
    this.Show=false;
    this.edit=false;
  }
  addEmployee()
  {
    console.log()
    this.employees.push(this.model);
    this.Show = true;
 this.add=false;
    this.model = {};
  }

  deleteEmployee(i){
    this.employees.splice(i,1)
    this.Show=true;
    console.log(i);
  }
  editEmployee(k){
    this.edit = true;
    this.Show=false;
    this.add=false;
    if(name!="")
    {
      this.model2.name = this.employees[k].name;
    }
    this.model2.position = this.employees[k].position;
    this.model2.salary = this.employees[k].salary;
    this.myValue = k;
  }
  updateEmployee(){
    this.Show=true;
    this.edit = false;
    let k = this.myValue;
    for(let i=0;i<this.employees.length;i++){
      if(i==k)
      {
        this.employees[i]= this.model2;
        this.model2 = {};
      }
    }
  }

}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

what did i had wrong??

Comment: What is the `if(name!="")` check for? Where is the `name` coming from? Something about this isn't right. You don't seem to have a `name` declared anywhere.

Comment: yes that was the problem thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove  following check from function editEmployee()

```
if(name!="") // Remove this if
    {
      this.model2.name = this.employees[k].name;
    }
```

It should be  `this.model2.name = this.employees[k].name;`

Comment: can we connect this data to mongodb using REST APIs??

Comment: Yes we can you need to set up mogodb and create service using java, node or wherever you want then write procedure for storing and retrieving. By the way accept this answer if that works works for you.

Comment: can u post any good tutorial related to my topic?? like storing two inputs fields into the mongodb using node code with REST APIs??

Comment: var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb";

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var myobj = { name: "Company Inc", address: "Highway 37" };
  db.collection("customers").insertOne(myobj, function(err, res) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("1 document inserted");
    db.close();
  });
});

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/the-modern-application-stack-part-2-using-mongodb-with-nodejs

Comment: Please refer above 4 comments. By the way accept this answer if that works works for you.

Comment: wat is that code all about... i am unable to understand it

Comment: That was basic code to connect with mongo db and insert you data, but you need to learn how to create nodejs server and api, then call this server from front end and using nodejs mongodb api you need to store your data. If do not find anything to accept then you vote for this answer! Thanks.